# Slideshow images are not appearing as a slideshow and instead appearing underneath each other

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone hope you are well, I'm trying to get a slideshow to work, it's literally similar to the one on w3schools as an example yet mine isn't working.

The slideshow needs to go into the "main" container and be the exact same width and height as the "main" container.

However, putting the slideshow into the container creates a hell of a mess, the images do not become slideshow and instead the images appear under one another, stretching the entire "main" container and messing up the button container and the footer container.

How can I fix this? I followed the w3schools example almost directly just to get it to work yet I just mess it up even more. I would appreciate any help I can get, thank you.

The css code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

<div class="slider-container fade">
  <div class="slider-images">
    <img src="images/marsrover.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Visit the original Mars rover landing sites!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-images fade">
    <img src="images/sandboarding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Go sandboarding on the Martian dunes!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-images fade">
    <img src="images/luxurymall.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Explore thousands of unique Martian crafted luxuries</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-images fade">
    <img src="images/nightskydesert.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Stargaze with a light pollution free sky!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-images fade">
    <img src="images/sandbuggy.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Ride sandbuggy's across the martian surface!</div>
  </div>

.slider-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.slide-images {
  display: none;
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Here is how it should look like, the "Main" container is where the slideshow should fit, the slideshow should be exactly the same size as the container:

https://jsfiddle.net/voltaicseas/sfbu7z10/1/

```
<!doctype html>


  <div class="item3">main</div>
```

Here is what I have done, I tried putting the code into "Item3" which is the "Main" container (coloured yellow to guide me), as you can see it completely messes up the layout of the page and the images don't even appear as a slideshow and instead just appear underneath one another.

https://jsfiddle.net/voltaicseas/ah4oznLp/

```
  <div class="item3">
    <div class="slider-container fade">
      <div class="slider-container fade">
        <div class="slider-images">
          <img src="images/marsrover.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Visit the original Mars rover landing sites!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-images fade">
          <img src="images/sandboarding.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Go sandboarding on the Martian dunes!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-images fade">
          <img src="images/luxurymall.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Explore thousands of unique Martian crafted luxuries</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-images fade">
          <img src="images/nightskydesert.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Stargaze with a light pollution free sky!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-images fade">
          <img src="images/sandbuggy.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Ride sandbuggy's across the martian surface!</div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the minimal amount of code to address this issue? What you've provided looks like an entire html document; you should provide just slideshow part of the site so that we can focus on it.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I removed everything that isn't related to my question.